# There is override and hidden method exist in derived class. Why?

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, overriding, hidden

There is a code sample:

```
public class A 
{
    public virtual void M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");

    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }

}

public class C : B
{
    public new virtual void M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }
}

public class D : C
{
    public override void M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D");
    }
}



internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        C c = new C();
        foreach (var method in typeof (C).GetMethods().Where(_ => _.Name == "M"))
        {
            method.Invoke(c, new object[0]);
        }
        c = new D();
        foreach (var method in typeof(D).GetMethods().Where(_ => _.Name == "M"))
        {
            method.Invoke(c, new object[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

I got that overridden method exists in hierarchy even in the case it was hidden by next ierarchy level class. Can you explain me why? Or just give me a link so i can find out? Thanks.

Comment: Because the method is hidden, not removed? They would have called it "method removing" and not "method hiding" if it really removed the method.

Answer (score 3):

That's the idea of hiding something - it still exists.

If C# wouldn't allow this kind of hiding, they'd have to disallow using method names if they already exist in a base class.

The base class method still exist; otherwise the base class would no longer function properly. You just can't access it directly from the class instance that derives from it:

```
C c = new C();
c.M(); // returns C
((B)c).M(); // returns B
```

Comment: Well. So that's it. I just thought that there was something more than that. Thanks.